# (Beginner) MYSQL: What can I do about this where statement?

Tags: mysql, select, where

Suppose I have some table named tableA and column1 in tableA has some null values and strings.

Also suppose I had created some temporary table named tempTable that has only 1 column. And that 1 column contains null values and strings as well.

I have a statement similar to the following:

```
select *
from tableA
where tableA.column1 in (select * from tempTable);
```

However, I want it to also select the contents when tableA.column1 is null. The in operator ignores that case.

Is there a different operator that considers null?

Or is there anyway I can apply certain constraints in the where clause under true or false conditions.

Like for example in the incorrect statement below:

```
select *
from tableA
where (if condition1, then tableA.column1 =.... elseif condition2 then tableA.column1 =....);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT tableA.*
FROM tableA
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT column1
       FROM tempTable ) temp ON tableA.column1 <=> temp.column1
```

`<=>` is null-safe compare operator. It assumes that NULL is equal to NULL whereas regular comparing operator `=` considers them unequal.

Subquery is used for to collapse equal values in tempTable - if not then each value from tableA may be selected a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

If you want al NULL from column1, simply add a OR clöause that check if ULL

```
select *
from tableA
where tableA.column1 in (select column1 from tempTable) OR tableA.column1 IS NULL;
```

Comment: If `tableA` contains NULLs whereas `tempTable` does not then this query will give wrong result.

Comment: @Akina As i understand the wuery, he will all rows that also are in the temptable and all NULL Rows from TableA, so i think that is a correct answer. I am not completely sure, but after work i will test the theory, your query should produce a cross join, because many NULL from tablea will be joined with NULL Values from temptable. So my query should yield the correct result.

Comment: *As i understand the wuery, he will all rows that also are in the temptable and all NULL* I see. If the rows with NULLs must be returned unconditionally then your query is correct.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should of been clear.  tempTable may or may not contain null. So @Akina's solution is what I needed.